# Show a PDF document in a browser without the menu bar

Tags: html, pdf

I have a touch screen kiosk that displays a webpage and a pdf document. Can I remove the menu bar? Users must not have "save", "print" and other such features.

Update

[random screenshot on flickr](http://flickr.com/photos/23021917@N05/2209106577/) - I am refering to the print, back/forward, zoom bar that controls the PDF -- not the browser menu. Sorry for not beeing specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - you should be able to set up most of that in the pdf document itself.

This is going from the menus in Acrobat Pro 9:
 File -> Properties -> Initial View

There are some options there for: Hide menu bar, tool bars, window controls

This has been around in acrobat for a while, so most version should do it.

It is alo possible to set these programmatically if you have the right libraries, but easiest to download a demo of acrobat.

Answer (score 2):

OpenOffice also has options to hide controls and forbid printing under:
`File->Export as PDF->User Interface`
Unfortunately, you can't modify current PDFs.  You'll have to have a Word or OOorg document to export.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use [PDF Open Parameters](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Good discussion on using IE7 in Kiosk mode:
http://samanathon.com/internet-explorer-7s-kiosk-mode/

---

If Firefox is on option for you, see this plugin:

> [R-kiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1659)
>
> *Real Kiosk is a Firefox 2.0 - 3.0 extension that defaults to full screen, disables all menus, toolbars, key commands and right button menus. Alt+Home still takes you home*

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a machine with the .net framework you could throw together a windows forms app with an embedded web browser control, which gives you a little more control (how do they go back from pdf without a toolbar or a right click?)

But the quickest option that I have used (done a few touchscreens) is just using IE in kiosk mode, which is easily accomplished with command line switches, and setting that to run fullscreen on windows startup.

Answer (score 0):

u need pdf professional version to do that when you create the pdf file,
File -- Properties -- Initial Vies
check the "Hide menu bar" and "Hide tool bars"
Save

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Or just use this open source component and get rid of acrobat reader

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/